# How configure a SSL certificate for LDAP

Tags: php, active-directory, ldap, ssl-certificate

I made a php code to unlock and change user's password on Active Directory. The program is working fine, but just a standard LDAP connection is not secure enough to change the password. So, I need to configure a SSL certificate, but I have no Idea how to do it. My environment consist in a Domain Controller and a Centos 7 server to host my application. I installed an ADCS too but no success on it too.

Comment: Your subject line doesn't actually state the question you are asking.  A better subject line would be `How do I configure a SSL certificate for LDAP?`

Comment: I assume the AD-Server already has a TLS Certificate and your question is about how to connect securely to that Ad-Server. Is that a self-signed certificate? And have you tried connecting via 'ldaps' or using STARTTLS? Or are you asking how to configure your AD for STARTTLS?